# Can SQLite databases be shared across a Windows service and user application?

Tags: windows, sqlite, service, share

In my product I want to share data using SQLite between a Windows service and a user-level application. However, I have been running into some problems.

When the user-level application creates the SQLite database, both programs are able to use it without issue. But if the service creates the SQLite database, then SQLite seems to handle concurrency very badly. The service process seems to keep a write lock for as long as the database connection is active. Attempts by the user-level process result in shared-memory-related errors (I've seen `SQLITE_IOERR_SHMOPEN` and `SQLITE_IOERR_SHMMAP`) instead of the normal `SQLITE_LOCKED` error. Of course, when the service closes its connection to the database, the user-level process gains access again.

The service is running as the `LOCAL_SERVICE` user and the SQLite database is in a shared system directory (`C:\ProgramData\...`) **and using write-ahead logging (edit)**.

My theory is that SQLite is not able to share memory between the user-level process and the service, thus making it impossible to have two simultaneous connections held by those processes.

Has anyone dealt with this? Is there a solution besides trying really hard to keep both processes from needing the database simultaneously?

Comment: Services run under another user account. And do you have enabled WAL?

Comment: Yes, we're using write-ahead logging.

Comment: What is the ACL of the directoy where SQLite creates the `-shm` file?

Comment: Should that matter? Both processes are able to use the file, just not at the same time. (One databases connection at a time, it seems.)

Comment: I should add, when the processes let go of their database connections quickly, the busy timeout of 10 seconds seems to handle locking issues just fine. But I would expect that even if a process holds a database connection for more than 10 seconds, there should not be a problem.

Comment: I'll see what the ACLs look like in case. It seems that the files created for WAL are deleted after a database connection is closed, so permissions could be an issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was related to the fact that the service was creating the folder (in which the SQLite database was created) with restrictive permissions. Once we started creating the folder with write permissions for anyone in the *Users* group, the problem went away.